# Docker Portainer /templates.json: permission denied - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sudo, docker

I'm trying to start a container for Portainer but it's not starting and in the log it shows the message:

```
2020/06/16 16:31:12 Warning: the --template-file flag is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future version of Portainer.
2020/06/16 16:31:14 Unable to retrieve template definitions via filesystem
2020/06/16 16:31:14 open /templates.json: permission denied
```

I did the following steps:

1. docker pull portainer/portainer
2. docker volume create portainer_data
3. docker run -d -p 9000:9000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v portainer_data:/data --name portainer_container portainer/portainer

Does anybody know how to fix this error? The container is created, but when I try to start, after 5 seconds, it shutdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the instructions on docker website and it worked.

[Deployment Portainer](https://portainer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment.html)